# Javascript join two JSON arrays

Tags: javascript

I have A JSON file with two arrays,
I would like to be able to get the name of the Receiver under "Rcvr in the ACLIST `acList.Rcvr` from the second array from the FEED Object.

The relationship is the ACLIST Rcvr to the FEEDS id then return the name.

```
acList.Rcvr === feed.id

// Sample output
var output = {["rcvr": 2, "name": "NZMB1"]};
```

I believe this can be done with concat? But I have had no luck.

The feeds:

```
"feeds": [
  {"id": 1, "name": "NZWP1"}, 
  {"id": 2, "name": "NZMB1"}, 
  {"id": 3, "name": "PUB_VRS"}, 
  {"id": 4, "name": "NZAP1"}]
```

ACLIST:

```
"acList": [{
  "Id": 11363733,
  "Rcvr": 2,
  "HasSig": false,
  "Icao": "AD6595",
  "Bad": false,
  "Reg": "N962WN",
  "FSeen": "\/Date(1533936304145)\/",
  "Stops": ["PIT", "BWI", "PBI", "TPA", "STL"],
  "Op": "Southwest Airlines",
  "Year": "2011"
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have had no luck"? What is the expected result and what are you currently getting?

Comment: It would be easier to join the arrays before converting to JSON: `let arr1 = [1, 2]; let arr2 = [3, 4]; let arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]; // [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Not even clear what the relationship is between the two to match them with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out away to do it.

```
var feedslist = [];
for (i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++){
    if (feeds[i].id == p.Rcvr) {
        feedslist.push(feeds[i].name);
    } else if (feedslist != feeds[i].name) {
        feedslist.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

$(" #rcvr").text(feedslist);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a map and lookup.  You still need to define the relationship though...  It's not stated what the *join* is.

```js
 let acList= [
  { "Rcvr": 1, "name": "NZWP1", "polarPlot": false }, 
  { "Rcvr": 2, "name": "NZMB1", "polarPlot": false}
 ];

 let feeds = [
  { "id": 2, "name": "NZMB1", "polarPlot": false},
  { "id": 3, "name": "NZWP1", "polarPlot": false } 
 ];

let res = feeds.map(feed=>{
  let lookup = acList.find(ac=> {
    //TODO return true when ac relates to feed
    if(ac.Rcvr === feed.id) return true
  })
  return {
    name:feed.name,
    rcvr: lookup  } // lookup.Rcvr
})
console.log("res =", res)
```

Comment: Please justify the downvote.  I really would like to know why this does not solve the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that Wasn't me so not sure why.

Comment: Hi @StevenSpungin could you help to make it run. This line `{ name:feed.name, rcvr: lookup.Rcvr}` throws the error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Rcvr')`

Comment: Are you using another data set?  That error might show up if the feeds list had an invalid value.

Comment: acList, not feeds list